# How to add checks for a particular type

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Often times I find myself in a situation where my types are extremely similar to base types in Python, but they have some certain property that I'd like the typecheckers to know about.

For example, I may have `ColorValue = NewType('ColorValue', int)` where a `ColorValue` should have a range between 0 and 255.

Then, what I'd like to have happen is for the typechecker to let me know if I'm not actually matching the type specifications. For example, something like:

```py
red: ColorValue = 300 # value of 300 is not compatible with type ColorValue
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to set something like this up with

```
ColorValue = NewType('ColorValue', int, check=lambda value: 0 <= value <= 255)
```

Is there any way to have type checkers check for specific properties?

EDIT:

To be clear, **I'd like this checking to be done by a type checker like mypy or pytype, and I don't want the error to only occur during runtime.**

Comment: not with `=` since it will bind the old name with the right hand part. You need a class and a setter/property method

Comment: To me, this sounds like something to handle via input validation when the object is created, rather than a check after the fact. If `300` is an invalid number for your `ColorValue` object, you shouldn't be allowing it to be created in the first place

Comment: I know that the class should not allow that to happen, but that's only caught during runtime (right?). I would like this type of error to be caught during typechecking.

Comment: Are you asking about `isinstance`? Otherwise I don’t understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you using a third-party type checker? Python itself does not do any type checking, regardless of whether or not you added type annotations. `check=lambda value: 0 <= value <= 255` seems to imply a runtime check, though...

Comment: Yes, I want this functionality from a third-party type checker

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following module called "restrict.py"

```
def restrict(cls, cache=[]):  
    cache.append(cls)
    return cls

def static_check(file, restrict):
    import re        
    cache = restrict.__defaults__[0]   
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for cls in cache:
        c = cls.__name__
        for lix, l in enumerate(lines):
            m = re.findall(f"{c}[^=)]*\)", l)
            for m in m:
                try:
                    print("Attempting", m)
                    strargs = m.split(c)[1]
                    cmd = f"cls{strargs}"
                    eval(cmd)
                    print(m, "in line", lix, "evaluated")
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(m, "in line", lix,"threw",e)
```

and another module called main.py, which you want to test

```
from restrict import restrict, static_check

@restrict
class Restricted():
    def __new__(cls, x:int=None) -> int:
        if x is None:
            raise ValueError("Unspecified initialization")
        elif x < 0:
            raise(ValueError("<0"))
        elif x > 255:
            raise(ValueError(">255"))
        return int(x)

def output_foo(x):
    Restricted(-1)
    return Restricted(999)

Restricted(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    static_check(__file__, restrict)
```

running `python main.py` from the terminal will print you

```
Attempting Restricted()
Restricted() in line 5 threw Unspecified initialization
Attempting Restricted(-1)
Restricted(-1) in line 16 threw <0
Attempting Restricted(999)
Restricted(999) in line 17 threw >255
Attempting Restricted(1)
Restricted(1) in line 19 evaluated
```

Not protecting the static_check with the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause would allow you to check at import time.

## OLD ANSWER

You could check at parse time, e.g. assume you have a file named `restricted.py` with the following code:

```
class Restricted():

    def __new__(cls, x):
        import sys
        lineno = sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno
        if x < 0:
            print(f"Value {x} is too low in line {lineno}")
        if x > 255:
            print(f"Value {x} is too high in line {lineno}")
        return int(x)

def invalid_foo(x:Restricted=Restricted(300)):
    return x

def valid_foo(x:Restricted=Restricted(222)):
    return x
```

which prints `Value 300 is too high in line 13` when you would import the module / parse the code, e.g. from bash with `python restricted.py` in addition to `mypy restricted.py`.

Apparently, neither mypy nor pytype alone printed the message, so it seems they actually do not import the module, and instead parse the file directly. One could fuse type checking and importing in bash with `tpcheck() { mypy $1  &&  python $1; }` and then you could call `tpcheck restricted.py` to do both.

Just to note: NewType does not actually create a new class. as the _doc__ says: "At runtime, NewType(name, tp) returns a dummy function that simply returns its argument".

An alternative option could be automatic unit test generation, e.g. with `auger-python`. For example, when we add the following code to the earlier snippet:

```
def output_foo():
    return Restricted(999)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import auger

    with auger.magic([Restricted]):
        output_foo()
```

tpcheck also showed me the error in the output_foo, i.e. `Value 999 is too high in line 22`. Please note that i exhibited a bug with auger, which i had to fix manually (see https://github.com/laffra/auger/issues/23). Additionally, mypy complained about a missing import for auger, so i had to redefine `tpcheck() { mypy $1 --ignore-missing-imports &&  python3 $1; }`.

But in the end, this boils down to calling the function, and executing it at run-time. Can't see how you could evade that, but at least you could try to automatize this as much as feasible.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but not quite, because I can still do `def another_valid_foo(): return Restricted(300)` and that won't raise any warning until I actually run the function.

Comment: Consider that ```check``` could be an arbitrarily complex function, and that ```Restricted(300)``` is essentially a placeholder for an arbitrary class instantiation. So we are searching for a code parser, which evaluates all class instantiations in the code, where all (or more complicated, some) of the  arguments are literals. I find it challenging to see how this does not imply a run-time check. So, what might solve your question is automatic unit test generation, e.g. with auger.

Comment: "Literal types indicate that some expression has literally a specific value" https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/, apparently annotations like ```Literal[1, 2, 3]``` will then allow such static checking. Looking forward!